# Swift Mediator Pattern - Collection of generic protocols

Tags: swift, generics, design-patterns, mediator

I am trying to implement a general-purpose [Mediator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) in Swift and have the following protocols and classes:

```
protocol Request {
}

protocol Handler {
    associatedtype TRequest = Request

    func handle(_ request: TRequest)
}

class RequestProcessor {

    func register<THandler: Handler>(_ handler: THandler) {

    }

    func handle(_ request: Request) {

    }

}
```

With the intended usage being (for example):

```
struct LoginRequest: Request {
    let username: String
    let password: String
}

struct LogoutRequest: Request {
    let userId: Int
}

class LoginHandler: Handler {
    func handle(_ request: LoginRequest) {
        // do something
    }
}

class LogoutHandler: Handler {
    func handle(_ request: LogoutRequest) {
        // do something
    }
}

// Setup the processor and register handlers

let processor = RequestProcessor()
processor.register(LoginHandler())
processor.register(LogoutHandler())

// The processor handles any kind of Request, in this case a LoginRequest

processor.handle(LoginRequest(username: "steve", password: "..."))

// The LoginHandler's handle method will be called
```

However I'm not sure how to store the collection of `Handler` objects since it is a protocol with associated type. I am aware of type-erasure and have read several answers here as well as various articles on the subject ([1](http://robnapier.net/erasure), [2](https://www.natashatherobot.com/swift-type-erasure/)) but am unsure how to apply it to my situation.

Comment: I would remove `associatedType` constraint from `Handler` so it will be `protocol Handler {
    func handle(_ request: Request)
}`. Now we can declare an `array` of `Handlers` inside `RequestProcessor `.

Answer (score 4):

First, the standard advice:

> I am trying to implement a general-purpose Mediator pattern in Swift

Don't. Start with the actual problem you're trying to solve, and design good and *necessary* abstractions for that problem. Don't create generic things just to be generic. Swift will bite you over and over again. Even stdlib, which really *needs* super-generic things, often has to step outside of pure Swift to pull it off (using compiler special knowledge, and gyb templating). "Being generic" is not a goal in itself. You're almost certainly making this too complicated. Everyone does.

OK, that's out of the way. Second piece of advice: This is not a good use of a protocol with associated types (PAT). The point of a PAT is to add methods to types, not to *be* types. You never pass `Collection` itself or store things of that "type." You create methods that can generically work on any type that is a `Collection`. There is no such type as `[Collection]`.

The fundamental problem with your approach is that there's no way to implement `RequestProcessor.process()` without resorting to `as?` casting, which breaks the point of type safety. How does `processor` know to call `LoginHandler.process`? Why that one? What if two different handlers accepted `LoginRequest`? What if no handler accepts that type?

What you've designed here isn't the Mediator pattern. The Mediator pattern joins together colleagues who share a single interface, so it would look like this:

```
class RequestProcessor<Request> {

    var handlers: [(Request) -> Void] = []
    func register(handler: @escaping (Request) -> Void) {
        handlers.append(handler)
    }

    func handle(request: Request) {
        for handler in handlers {
            handler(request)
        }
    }
}
```

And you'd have a `RequestProcessor` for each kind of request, not a generic "processor of every kind of request." Creating a generic one necessarily (in Swift) removes type safety, in which case you're basically creating a slightly Swiftier `NotificationCenter`. (It's possible to create a type-safe version of this, but it requires dependent types, which is a quite complex type feature that Swift doesn't have.)

OK, so maybe you really want this central hub and who needs type safety? Why not? You just have to say what you mean, which is that any handler has to be able to accept any request, even if it doesn't act on it. The compiler can't prove anything more specific than that because at compile time it doesn't know the types. So fine, `as?` it to death.

```
protocol Request {}

protocol Handler {
    func canHandle(_ request: Request) -> Bool
    func handle(_ request: Request)
}

class RequestProcessor {

    private var handlers: [Handler] = []

    func register(_ handler: Handler) {
        handlers.append(handler)
    }

    func handle(_ request: Request) {
        for handler in handlers where handler.canHandle(request) {
            handler.handle(request)
        }
    }
}

class LoginHandler: Handler {
    func canHandle(_ request: Request) -> Bool {
        return request is LoginRequest
    }

    func handle(_ request: Request) {
        guard let loginRequest = request as? LoginRequest else { return }
        // handle loginRequest
    }
}
```

But I'd almost certainly get rid of the Mediator pattern. If the goal is to swap in and out processors for testing or whatnot, I'd just use typical dependency injection techniques. Pass the `LoginHandler` to whatever method creates the `LoginRequest`.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer, I appreciate the push away from potentially going down completely the wrong path. The reasoning is purely academic, I'm not trying to solve a specific problem, rather trying to port the .NET [Mediatr](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki#basics) library to Swift, with a bit of learning thrown in for good measure. I think I can live with a variation of the last example you gave but pulling the `guard` / `as?` clauses into the processor and have the handlers be explicit about the request they handle, probably with a base class rather than a protocol.

Comment: I think you'll find you can't move the `as?` clause to the caller, because any `Handler` must implement some `handle` method that accepts the same type. You can't call a method using a type that isn't known at compile-time. While an interesting problem, I would recommend against porting a framework that solves a C# problem (likely driven by the pre-3.0 lack of first-class functions), and instead reimagine the *underlying* problem using Swift tools (particularly first-class functions), and focusing on Swift problems. Most "patterns" are not nearly as universal as they claim to be.